# runtime error with this code have numberformatexception

Tags: java

```
String a = jTextField1.getText();
String b = jTextField2.getText();
int c = Integer.parseInt(b);
jTextField3.setText(a);
```

Why is it not giving any value in the `textfield3`?
it shows `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Integer.parseInt(b) throw numberformatexception, you should try catch it

Comment: Yes, because the `NumberFormatException` causes the method to terminate. You could surround the `Integer.parseInt` with `try-catch`.

Comment: did you check what value is coming from a,b?

Answer (score 0):

You do some change then it will be correct like as

```
String b = jTextField2.getText().toStrong();
  int c = Integer.parseInt(b);
```